# Umbraco 8 - Checkbox (TrueFalse) Always returning False

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I'm trying to use the Checkbox/TrueFalse to toggle on/off certain parts of content, however it seems that no matter what setting I put the checkbox on, the Value (even parsed as Bool) always returns false.

I'm wondering if theres a property I'm missing, or if I'm somehow just completely doing it wrong.

```
@if(item.Value<bool>("includeButton")) {
    var linkUrl = item.Value<IPublishedContent>("buttonLink").Url;
    <a href="@linkUrl" class="Button Button--primary">@item.Value("buttonLabel")</a>
}
```

I've tried a few different methods, but to no success.

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This is a known issue inside Umbraco 8.0

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues/4812

Comment: I have only done this directly against Model properties so far in 8, however in my case I am able to just go directly to the property.  Try @if(item.IncludeButton")) {} should be no need to cast it.

Comment: @hardba11 will I need to enable strongly typed models for this?

Comment: are you in a loop there? If so,why? is it nested content or something of the sort?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, it's loop of items which each have option for a button, but just always returns false.